# Can XFire SOAP server send HTTP 301 REDIRECT to client?

Tags: java, http, soap, redirect

Is it possible to send a HTTP REDIRECT response from inside the XFire SOAP server instead of a regular response?

I need this in order to redirect the client to another server based on some checking of method parameters.

Also, is redirect handling something that major SOAP clients support? I know HttpClient does, but I'm not sure about .NET clients.

Answer (score 1):

Many soap clients won't follow redirects because you're not supposed to follow redirects on POSTs without confirmation from the user. (and all SOAP requests are POST)

Answer (score 0):

WS-BasicProfile 1.1 and 1.2 states that using HTTP temporary redirection 307 MAY work :

http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1_2%28WGAD%29.html#HTTP_Redirect_Status_Codes